# IBM as/400 developer kit for java

Tags: java

i am going to work on application which access some files from as/400 server.can anyone help me for installing as/400 developer kit in java so that i can start getting files from that server.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the jt400 driver. This supports various things such as (taken from the web site);

- Database -- JDBC (SQL) and record-level access (DDM)
- Integrated File System
- Program calls (RPG, COBOL, service programs, etc)
- Commands
- Data queues
- Data areas
- Print/spool resources
- Product and PTF information
- Jobs and job logs
- Messages, message queues, message files
- Users and groups
- User spaces
- System values
- System status

All the information you need is here: http://jt400.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Actually its not importing com.ibm.as400.access.*